# How can I make Windows 10 ignore all keyboard and mouse input for the next X seconds?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, mouse, lock-screen

I just spilled a whole cup of coffee all over my keyboard and desk. After cursing the situation, I pressed ***WinKey + L*** to enter the "lock mode" state of a Windows PC, where the only thing shown (at least in theory) is like a plain color with an input field for typing your password to "unlock" the machine so that it gets back to a usable state. Then I started cleaning up the mess.

Since randomly pressing a bunch of keys (Enter in particular) in this "lock mode" causes all kinds of weird stuff to happen on the screen, it always feels "scary"; as if I'm always one keypress away from accidentally shutting off the computer, deleting all the system files or permanently corrupting all my most important data. After it inevitably fails to log in with the random gibberish passwords entered followed by Enter, it starts taking more and more time before displaying the "login error" message, most likely as a security feature to make it more and more frustrating to sit and guess somebody else's password.

When I finally was done cleaning up (the Ctrl key had somehow remapped itself to Page Up, so I had to replace the entire keyboard anyway), and actually typed in my real password and pressed Enter, it took forever for it to "think about it", probably because it had "built up" a longer and longer timeout due to all the failed attempts.

Thus: ***Is there some way to make Windows enter a temporary state in which it ignores all keyboard/mouse input, allowing you to safely clean the plugged-in keyboard and mouse without any issues?***

Ideally, it would be like a command you type such as:

```
ignoreallinput.exe /t 30
```

To make it display a big counter saying "30 seconds left", "29 seconds left", "28 seconds left", etc. until it starts accepting input again.

Please let there be such a thing, and please let it not be some scary third-party utility...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option for you is to simply unplug the usb keyboard and mouse. They are most likely USB powered, so just unplug the keyboard, clean them, then put them back in.

That way, no electricity flows through the keyboard which could damage the keyboard if the liquid somehow short circuits the device. (yes they should have protection against it, but better safe than sorry, right!)

If you really need a state where windows does not recognize and respond to keyboard presses without unplugging the keyboard, press the powerbutton on your pc. This will send a shut down command to windows, and it will safely shutdown the computer. This will eliminate the need to press any keys or move the mouse and once the system is turned off, Windows will not act weird for keypresses.